# C# TreeView select and focus elements

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I implemented a TreeView in C# with a MVVM Pattern based on the Load-On-Demand Demo in [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode) description. Afterwards I tried to add a function to not only select, but also focus elements inside the TreeView. Therefore I implemented this class:

```
namespace TreeViewWithViewModelDemo.LoadOnDemand
{ 
  public static class FocusExtension{
    public static bool GetIsFocused(DependencyObject obj){
      return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsFocusedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsFocused(DependencyObject obj, bool value){
      obj.SetValue(IsFocusedProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFocusedProperty =
      DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
          "IsFocused", typeof(bool), typeof(FocusExtension),
          new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsFocusedPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnIsFocusedPropertyChanged(
         DependencyObject d,
         DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e){
      var uie = (UIElement)d;
      if ((bool)e.NewValue) {
         uie.Focus(); // Don't care about false values.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And inside my TreeViewItemViewModel.cs I added the parameter IsTextBoxFocused:

```
private bool _isFocused = true;
public bool IsTextBoxFocused
{
  get{ return _isFocused; }
  set
  {
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (_isFocused == value)
    {
      _isFocused = false;

      if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsTextBoxFocused"));
    }
    _isFocused = value;
    if (handler != null)
      handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsTextBoxFocused"));
  }
}
```

In my XAML I changed the HierarchicalDataTemplate for the regions:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate 
      DataType="{x:Type local:RegionViewModel}" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"
      >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Grid local:FocusExtension.IsFocused="{Binding IsTextBoxFocused}" Focusable="True">
            <Grid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Rename"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </Grid.ContextMenu>
            <!-- Normal state of the header -->
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockHeader" Focusable="True" Text="{Binding RegionName}" Margin="3,0" />
            <!-- This state is active in the edit mode -->
          </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Until here my Code works perfectly fine, but only for the Region nodes in my Tree. In the next step I tried to let the State nodes also be focused. Therefore I implemented a new variable IsGridBoxFocused the same way I did with IsTextBoxFocused. In my XAML I changed the HierarchicalDataTemplate for the states:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate 
      DataType="{x:Type local:StateViewModel}" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Children}"
      >
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Grid local:FocusExtension.IsFocused="{Binding IsGridBoxFocused}" Focusable="True">
                <Grid.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Rename"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Grid.ContextMenu>
                <!-- Normal state of the header -->
                <TextBlock x:Name="textBlockHeader" Focusable="True" Text="{Binding StateName}" Margin="3,0" />
                <!-- This state is active in the edit mode -->
             </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

At last I changed the IsSelected funtion.
In TreeViewItemViewModel:

```
public virtual bool IsSelected
{
    get { return _isSelected; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _isSelected)
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            if (!_isSelected)
            {
              this.IsExpanded = false;
            }
            else
            {
              this.IsExpanded = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the RegionViewModel:

```
public override bool IsSelected
{
  get
  {
     return base.IsSelected;
  }

  set
  {
    base.IsSelected = value;
    IsTextBoxFocused = value;
    if (value == true)
    {
      foreach (var elem in this.Children)
      {
        elem.IsGridBoxFocused = !value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And in the StateViewModel:

```
public override bool IsSelected
{
  get
  {
    return base.IsSelected;
  }
  set
  {
    IsGridBoxFocused = value;
    Parent.IsTextBoxFocused = !value;
    base.IsSelected = value;
  }
}
```

My Problem is, when I select a Region node it works fine, when i select a State(Child) node the first time it also works, but when I select a second State node a parent node is selected instead. Can somebody help me with this problem?

Comment: Questions asking *why this code doesn't work* should provide a sample that reproduces the problem. When adding these changes to the CodeProject demo you mention, xaml throws error *"local is an undeclared prefix"*.

Comment: My bad. I edited my post, so I think it should be reproducable now